# What is the default layout background

Tags: android, html, android-layout, background-color

I got a WebView that load an HTML file with a text. The problem is that the color inside the html and outside isn't the same. Here is a screenshot:

[image: The Activity With the WebView]

The HTML FIle is:

```
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
    <title>About</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>

    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <p>This is a Testpp</p>
        <p>See the problem.</p>
         <p>last test:</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

(If I remove the: `bgcolor="#FFFFFF"` color stays the same)
Thanks!

Comment: The default background color of an Android layout? I think it's nothing, or in other words black.

Comment: Its black. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I edited the Question please look again.

Comment: the background color is based on your application theme, and is not a color at all, but rather a drawable. what were you trying to achieve once you found out what the color is?

Comment: i want to change the html color to the same color like outside the html.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

The default background color for light theme is: #EEEEEE

Is almost white, but not completely.

It worked for me, hope its work for you.

UPDATE: In new versions you could be looking for #FAFAFA

Comment: It's the #EEEEEE still in android studio latest version. Thumbs up for this answer, thank you!

Comment: I have found my self that in later API version it changes, would you be so kind to check if it any difference between 21 and below please? Maybe I did something wrong with my project

Comment: #FAFAFA +1 for me, emulator API 25, Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: Thank you! May I ask where you can find this information, just in case it changes in the future?

Comment: @null_awe is either an image editing tool or is it a source code

Answer (score 126):

You can use your theme's default background color by referencing:

```
?android:colorBackground
```

Comment: android:background="?android:colorBackground" Works great! Any drawbacks with this solution?

Answer (score 33):

**To change your background (if this is in fact what you are looking to do):**

in styles.xml

```
<style name = "MyDefaultStyle" parent = "@android:style/Theme">
    <item name = "android:windowBackground">@drawable/default_drawable_bg</item>
</style>
```

and in your manifest

```
<application
    android:name="MyApp"
    android:theme="@style/MyDefaultStyle" >
```

Comment: No i don't want to change the background i want to know what is the background color.

Answer (score 14):

Go to Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.NoActionBar">
```

You see the Theme is MyMaterialTheme.NoActionBar

So go to res -> values -> styles
[image: Click open in editor]

[image: Click on the pallette for the background color]

[image: This is your background color]

So for me the default is #FFFAFAFA

When i put the suggested colors #EEEEEE or #FAFAFA, it worked on some phones, and on other phones it was off, so that's what I found with trial and error

Answer (score 1):

Default color is black.

If you use style, go to "values/styles.xml" and there is solution of you issue. Now you can check bg color.
About themes and styles : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

**EDIT :**

Layout background color changing - [Setting background colour of Android layout element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378636/setting-background-colour-of-android-layout-element)

**EDIT 2:**

If in styles.xml is @android:style/Theme.Light your bg color is white.

Comment: Thanks, but the styles.xml just saying which them is it(default:Theme.Light and API14:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar) and i want to know which background color is in that themes.(it isn't black) thanks!

Comment: In themeas are only black and white :D. Yu can change bg color in layou xml. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378636/setting-background-colour-of-android-layout-element .

Comment: it was useful but didn't answered my question

Comment: repeat your question in one sentence :

Comment: I want to know want is the background color in my app.I have no background color in the xml or the java code and in the styles.xml it's just says that the them is "android:Theme.Light".

Comment: So why when i do a WebView and show an HTML test file so it's more white then the layout background?(Edit: in "Theme.Holo.Light" it's white too?)

Answer (score 0):

The default background color for light theme is: #e6FFFFFF

Answer (score 0):

Default color for every layout in the latest update of android studio is: `#FFFFFF`