# Preserving View background colour on recreation of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I've just about got the concept of using the `Bundle` instance state to store stuff that wouldn't otherwise be stored when an `Activity` is destroyed and recreated (e.g. on screen rotation).  I also see that you don't need to do this for basic information for each `View`, like text in a `TextView`, because the system does that for you (at least for those Views that have an ID assigned).  See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html.

But when I change the background color of a `View` programmatically (I'm using a basic `View` as a color swatch linked to a color picker) using `setBackgroundColor()`, I find that the color is lost when the screen rotates, and reverts back to the original setting.  I do have an ID assigned to the `View`.

Should that color information be preserved automatically, or am I just being hopeful, and do I have to keep track of that separately and restore the color on recreation of the Activity?

Thanks.

Comment: How surprising, I found a page in the official BASIC training page by doing a simple Google Search : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html I wonder what prevented you to do the same ...

Comment: Can't you see that I put the very same link in my original post!!  So clearly I *did* bother searching and I *did* find that BASIC training page.  But I can't see any mention in the BASIC training page of preserving background colors, which is my particular issue.  Thanks for being so patronising though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes when you set your Background Color directly by View.setBackgroundColor() Always when the app is changed to landscape this is replace by the default layout. You should implement:

  `setContentView(R.layout."activitylayoutname");`
- And of course on the layout set a background parameters.

Edited 1:
Try this link to set background valúes:

[Setting background colour of Android layout element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378636/setting-background-colour-of-android-layout-element).

And also if you want to preserve other valúes between Activities, just recreate an activity:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Thanks.  I fit it a bit odd that Android doesn't preserve the colors on a screen re-orientation.  Anyhow, I've put some code into `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to do this myself, and it's working nicely.