# What will happen if used empty layout with background color in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

What will happen to the background color of Layout as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

**Case 1**
What will happen to background color of `RelativeLayout` if `Button` visibility set to "INVISIBLE"?

**Case 2**
What will happen to background color of `RelativeLayout` if `Button` visibility set to "GONE"?

Comment: Nothing will happen to background color of RelativeLayout if Button visibility set to invisible or gone.

Comment: You could have tried it yourself in lesser time

Comment: you could try it :D

Comment: i came across this question in one of my interviews; the interviewer explained that the background color of RelativeLayout will not be displayed in case it does not have any child.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I tried it already. But i wanted to know if there is any catch in it which i am doing wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not effect on the relative layout.after the button invisible the button is gone but you still got the relative layout with same background.
for more reference visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378636/setting-background-colour-of-android-layout-element) hope this help.:)

Comment: Thank you so much Pratik for the link. :)

Comment: @Pavan no problem happy coding.:)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.
As you are changing the background color of `Layout`, and NOT the Button itself !!