# Use current theme backgroundcolor in layout file

Tags: android, android-theme

I have 2 Themes, a dark and a bright one. I want to get the current themes background color and use it in a layout file like this:

```
<View
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="(backgroundColor)" />
```

Let's say `(backgroundColor)` is the current themes background color. What do I have to put in there instead of `(backgroundColor)`?

Comment: what is this!! what this `(backgroundColor)` suppose to mean?!

Comment: A placeholder for the background color, that I'm not able to obtain

Comment: I still don't understand your question but however you may want to see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378636/setting-background-colour-of-android-layout-element)

Comment: I tried to make my question more understandable. Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer to your question would probably be`?android:colorBackground`. But you might still want to use `?android:windowBackground` on some occasions.

While `windowBackground` will be the background of your activity, `colorBackground` seems like the *default* background color for your content.

In your case you would end up like the following:

```
<View
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="?android:colorBackground" />
```

---

For a full list of those "default" theme attributes you can check out the source code of the basic [Android themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml#48)

Answer (score 3):

use  `android:theme`

```
<View
    android:theme="@style/yourTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and in your values\styles.xml

```
 <style name="yourTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
 </style>
```

**Edit**: Please try to post your full question at the first time and if you make a change try to add it under edit section.  People who love to help you gets in trouble otherwise.

For your edited question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468034/5188159)

> You can get the background color (or Drawable) from the current theme
>   by:
>
> ```
> TypedValue a = new TypedValue();
> getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowBackground, a, true);
> if (a.type >= TypedValue.TYPE_FIRST_COLOR_INT && a.type <= TypedValue.TYPE_LAST_COLOR_INT) {
>     // windowBackground is a color
>     int color = a.data;
> } else {
>     // windowBackground is not a color, probably a drawable
>     Drawable d = activity.getResources().getDrawable(a.resourceId);
> }
> ```

and set it to your view!

Comment: Sorry about the inconvenience. I'm sorry to tell you, but I can't code in this matter, because it would turn my layouts and code into a mess. Thank you anyway